# Grails "production" dataSource reports issues that do not happen in "test" dataSource

Tags: postgresql, grails

We just ran into (and solved) an issue that was only reported by the JDBC driver for PostgreSQL. The in-memory H2 database passed the test, but when we changed our test database in `DataSource.groovy` to match the production one it fails.

```
// this data source allows a bug discovered in production to be hidden, 
// but can be run without additional setup
inMemoryTest {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
        url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
    }
}

// this data source reproduces the bug in production, but requires 
// additional setup
cloneOfProductionTest {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "create-drop" 
        driverClassName = "org.postgresql.Driver"
        username = "postgres"
        password = "****"
        url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/IntegrationTestDB"
    }
}
```

For the record the bug was that we didn't map the 'belongsTo' field on a one-to-many association and deletions were not cascading properly. H2 allowed the owner to be deleted, while PostgreSQL failed with a `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException`. We fixed it by modelling the depending class correctly, and now deletions cascade just fine.

Obviously I like finding bugs early, and for the moment we have our test data source a clone of the production one. Seems like a workaround though, and it would be nice to have the tests reliable without any prior setup by the developer running the tests (i.e., installing PostgreSQL and setting up a test database). Any suggestions?

Comment: How can you test any of this if your production database is on Postgres and your test is on H2?  Being honest that is completely wrong.  That's the same as having your production code written in ruby and your test environment using java.  Get your environments on the same database(version and platform too).  Until that time all your tests are of very little value if any.

Comment: I see your point. In grails by default the `test` environment is used in both unit tests and integration tests. Is your suggestion to have separate environments for unit and integration tests? It seems like a common practice to have unit tests operate on an embedded database, which is why I ask.

Answer (score 0):

"I see your point. In grails by default the test environment is used in both unit tests and integration tests. Is your suggestion to have separate environments for unit and integration tests? It seems like a common practice to have unit tests operate on an embedded database, which is why I ask."

No, I'm thinking higher level than that. My suggestion is that your path to prod is consistent.  You can't mix technology and versions between dev and prod and expect to have a soundly engineered system.  The only time a dev environment would switch out a version or technology is if your are working on moving your code line to that new version or technology so you can push it to production at some point.  And in that case you would typically still have a dev environment that matches production in case a production defect comes up while you are working on the next release(code branch).  I always keep a environment in-sync with prod and another environment that is for the next release.  In a perfect world you would even match hardware and data, but that is often not feasible unless your in the pace maker type of business where it's a requirement.

I will say that if it's common practice to have unit tests go against an embedded database, but production be on something else that is practice wrong and who ever is pushing it is wrong about that.

Comment: I guess I wasn't specific enough in the question. You are absolutely right. We do have a DEV-QA-PROD path, that tests the output of the package produced by `grails prod war` (i.e., the grails `production` environment). These are indeed clones of PROD. I guess my question is more specific to the concept of a grails `environment` during feature development on a local workstation than the testing process done once the application is packaged and deployed to the appropriate environment. (See http://grails.org/doc/2.2.4/guide/single.html#environments)

Comment: I updated the title which hopefully made things clearer.

Comment: I see where your coming from, but Postgres is free and easy to install why wouldn't require a developer to have it setup on their own machine where they do unit testing?

Comment: I guess my point is that we wouldn't be having this specific discussion if your tech stack was the same on the dev machine and other environments.:)

Comment: And that's a valid outcome of this question: to use PostgreSQL for both integration tests and deployment environments. But that also means using it for unit tests (or breaking grails convention by separating the two environments).